# swift: type of expression is ambiguous, execution failed

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

can any one help me to make this code compatible with swift 2

```
var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            var corners: UIRectCorner = .TopRight | .BottomRight
            imageView.image = image!.imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize(bounds.size).imageWithRoundedCornersSize(20, corners: corners)
        }
    }
```

and thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.0, many things that has been done with bit masks has removed and these types changed to be conformed to `OptionSetType` protocol, like `UIRectCorner`:

```
public struct UIRectCorner : OptionSetType
```

So, you can use `union` function, instead of binary operator '|', as below:

```
var image: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        var corners: UIRectCorner = UIRectCorner.TopRight.union(UIRectCorner.BottomRight)
        imageView.image = image!.imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize(bounds.size).imageWithRoundedCornersSize(20, corners: corners)
    }
}
```

Comment: Some description of what you changed, and why that works would be useful.  Code-only answers are considered "low quality" on StackOverflow.